# Image in the Tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

Hi i am a newbie to iOS.

I have implemented a tableview in ViewController1.In the tableview i am displaying tittle,detailText and disclosure indicator for the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                   reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}



cell.textLabel.text =[listTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

  cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"4mile";





return cell;
}
```

Everything works fine,Now i need a image before the disclosure indicator when i do it with

```
 UIImageView *accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
  accessoryView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"];
cell.accessoryView = accessoryView;
```

Disclosure indicator is replaced by the image.But i need both image along with disclosure indicator without using Custom cell.

How can i do it...? Help me out.

Thanks

[image]

similiar to the due date but at the place of time i need image

Comment: please provide screen shot where to display image

Comment: That really should be a custom cell

Comment: @Birendra  added screen shot

Comment: hi you got your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` have a fixed layout, depending on the style you use when you initialize it. You cannot change that layout, since the cell lays out its subviews as it prefers to have them.

add the `- (void)layoutSubviews` to your cell subclass like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f , 0.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);
}
```

else try this

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"];;
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 5, 20, 20)]; // customize the frame
 [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: @ Anbu anna i have tried customizing frame it overlaps on the detail text of the cell.

Comment: @Cyph3r - then change the x coordinates and try , surely works

Comment: @ Anbu i have tried changing x value, it works i need the image between detail text and disclosure arrow when x values comes over there it hides.

Comment: but i need image between them

Comment: @Cyph3r - bro, I dont know ur concept, but I am sure you change the x and y coordinates surey works, all the best

Comment: @ Anbu Thanks for your time bro

Comment: @Cyph3r - not like that , any way if my answer is useful accept my answer

Comment: i have added screenshot above

Comment: @Cyph3r - in my suggestion , create 2 labels progmaticaklly and then asign  the frame surely works , dont use `cell.textLabel` and `cell.detailTextLabel`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna add `UIImageView` to standard `UITableViewCell` you need add your `imageView` to `contentView` of cell and add all subviews like a `textLabel`, `detailTextLabel` and `accessoryView`

```
UIImageView *accessoryImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
accessoryImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:accessoryImageView];
```

or subclass of `UITableViewCell` and implement all views inside it

Comment: your image not displayed? or crashed

Comment: image comes but hiding Disclosure

Comment: Change the name of your `accessoryView`, the standard tableviewcell have a  uiview with the same name

Comment: image overlapping over the disclosure arrow and detail text

Comment: Yes and for this case you need create a custom uitableviewcell

Comment: without custom cell will i wont be do that